# GCloud Compute Project-Info Add-Metadata Hangs

Tags: gcloud

The following command doesn't exit on my system:

`gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata=itemname=itemvalue`

I am using powershell on windows, and I've also tested on a linux container in docker. In both environments, the metadata is updated, but the command never terminates.

If I provide an invalid key, or update to the existing value, I do get the output: `No change requested; skipping update for [project].` and the program exits. Performing an actual update produces the hang.

I need this command to terminate so that I can use it in a script. I would like to be able to check the exit code to ensure the update occurred successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't patient enough. In large projects, this operation can take significant time to process. Give the script several minutes to complete.